# Enable to Restore the database

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I have successfully downloaded the database file from the remote server.  When i try to restore it on my local system, it throws the following error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The backup was split between two or more different files.  You will need to have all the backup files to restore the database.

Either find the rest of the files that are in the backup set or perform another backup to a single file.

Comment: The solution is to find the other file or backup again to a single file.  I can't tell you where the other part of the file is because I don't know your system - find out who performed the backup and ask them.

Comment: Another possibility is that your backup file is corrupted.  In that cause you could try downloading it again.